# Filter Backends Django Rest Framework List API View

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, backend

Excuse me devs, I want to ask about Django generics List API View filter_backends, how can i return none / data not found when the param is wrong or empty?

```
# My Django Views
class FilterTablePVPlantByPVOwnerId(filters.FilterSet):
    id = filters.CharFilter(
        field_name='id', lookup_expr='exact')

    class Meta:
        model = TablePVPlant
        fields = ['id']

class PlantListByClientView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = TablePVPlant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlantListSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = FilterTablePVPlantByPVOwnerId

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.query_params:    
            response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
            response.data = {'status': 'success',
                         'data': response.data, 'msg': 'done'}
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Django and in Django Rest Framework these type of things are dealt with by raising [Exceptions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/):

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException


class BadParameter(APIException):
    status_code = 400
    default_detail = 'The parameter x is wrong or empty'
    default_code = 'bad_param'

# ...

class PlantListByClientView(generics.ListAPIView):
    # ...
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        if bad_param:
            raise BadParameter()
```

Some parts of the framework will raise exceptions for you, like, for example, serializes rising `ValidationError` when validation fails.